# uint16_t vs UInt16

Tags: objective-c, ios, c

I'm writing an iOS app, and I'm noticing I have a couple ways to define a fixed width 16bit unsigned integer.

1. uint16_t - defined in stdint.h
2. UInt16 - defined in MacTypes.h

As these are fixed width (and I'd assume same endian), what could possibly be Apple's reason to define their own version?

Comment: Some people find `UInt16` looks nicer than `uint16_t`. The latter is too C-ish perhaps. People are strange (to quote The Doors)

Comment: It's defined in CarbonCore, so it's effectively deprecated.  Perhaps it was used for faster/reliable types under an older OSX

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "user-defined" types existed before the standard types became part of the standard.

I use the standard types everywhere, except when directly using an interface that specifies the "user-defined" types.

Comment: Thanks; I believe that's exactly why.

Comment: The standard types existed long before Mac OS X existed. Unless this header is pre-OSX, I don't think the rationale makes sense.

Comment: A Google cache of a Wikipedia page had stated stdint.h was introduced in 1999. NeXT was written in like, 1990s, and Mac OS X (released in 2001) provided backwards support for the Carbon API. So it's likely that MacTypes.h is a pre-OSX header that was provided in OSX.